# Comparing Time And Date with this format HH.MM mm/dd/yyyy.

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to compare using The format of military time and Date like this `HH.MM mm/dd/yyyy`.
For Example:

## 1

```
08.25 06/10/2014 > 23.18 06/09/2014
```

Result is True because the day 10 is greater than day 09

## 2

```
23.25 06/10/2014 > 23.30 06/10/2014
```

Result is false because the mins 30 is greater than mins 25

## 3

```
24.25 06/10/2014 > 1.30 06/10/2014
```

Result is true because the hrs 24 is greater than hrs 1

The Priority is Year -> Month -> Day -> Hours -> mins.

Comment: what time of day is represented by `24.25`?  you **do not** have to format a proper date time variable to anything in order to compare it to another date time type.  Date Time types have their own internal format.  Formatting is only important when displaying it to a user.  If you are formatting a date time to string then comparing, you could be doing a Text compare.  The code would help determine what the problem is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like you are allowed to have non-standard time like `24.25`.
Then you can use the following strategy - extract date, add time, compare.

```
Public Shared Function ToDateTime(ByVal value As String) As DateTime
    Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(value, "^(?<hours>\d{1,2})\.(?<minutes>\d{2}) (?<date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})$")
    If Not m.Success Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("value")
    End If
    Dim dateOnly As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(m.Groups.Item("date").Value, "dd\/MM\/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    Dim hours As Integer = Integer.Parse(m.Groups.Item("hours").Value)
    Dim minutes As Integer = Integer.Parse(m.Groups.Item("minutes").Value)
    Return dateOnly.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(ToDateTime("08.25 06/10/2014") > ToDateTime("23.18 06/09/2014"))
Console.WriteLine(ToDateTime("23.25 06/10/2014") > ToDateTime("23.30 06/10/2014"))
Console.WriteLine(ToDateTime("24.25 06/10/2014") > ToDateTime("1.30 06/10/2014"))
```

Comment: Thanyou sir but how if my data is in the txtbox i will compare it into two textbox

Comment: @user3639154 if you check, you'll see that NET/RegEx is converting `"24.25 06/10/2014"` to `"00:25 07/10/2014"` (rightfully so, I'd say).  But then, `24.25 06/10/2014 > 1.30 06/10/2014` is also incorrect.

Comment: Good day again sir can I ask again? because Im having problem about your suggested code. How Can I do this Comparison with textbox like this:If ToDateTime(TextBox9.Text) > ToDateTime(time.Text) Then
                TimeError.ShowDialog()

Comment: My error message is not poping? what do you think is the problem here