# Convert dates with MMDDYYYY format to MM/DD/YYYY using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How do I add slashes ( **/** ) to a date in VB.net?

If the date is in format **`MMDDYYYY`** then I'd like to convert it into **`MM/DD/YYYY`**.

For example: if the date is `07032014` then the output should be `07/03/2014`.

Comment: Dates are not **in** any format, we do **display them** in various formats for various reasons.  `mydt = #7/3/2014# // Console.WriteLine(mydt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))`.  About the top 6 of the questions on the right under **"Related"** apply

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing Time And Date with this format HH.MM mm/dd/yyyy.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132555/comparing-time-and-date-with-this-format-hh-mm-mm-dd-yyyy)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, you can manipulate the string or convert the string into a date.

```
    Dim str As String = "07032014"

    Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(0, 2) & "/" & str.Substring(2, 2) & "/" & str.Substring(4))
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MMddyyyy", Nothing).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

I would strongly suggest that you do not use strings for dates and use a proper date, especially if you are going to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the  [`Date.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) function to convert the string in to an actual date instance, then use  [`Date.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) with the specific format you want to convert that date back in to a string.

If you don't want to go that route you can rip the original string apart using [`String.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) and manually insert the slashes, but this is less robust.